# Insert tags in header via .Rmd

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

I'm using Rstudio to create Rmd reports, and I'd like to be able to insert meta tags into the `<head>` when the Rmd is knit into html.

From the documentation on [knitr options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options#package_options) I thought I could set the header option to insert text between the `<head>` tags like so:

````
```{r}
opts_knit$set(header = "<meta name=\"description\" content=\"this is a description\">")
```
````

However, nothing seems to be inserted. Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible?

Comment: that option only applies to R HTML (`.Rhtml`) and LaTeX (`.Rnw`); for Markdown, take a look at the `header` argument in `?markdown::markdownToHTML()`; besides, for RStudio, the customization of Markdown rendering is not very convenient yet, although possible

Comment: Thanks @Yihui. From ?markdown::markdownToHTML it looks like the `header` argument defaults to `getOption("markdown.HTML.header")`, so again, I initially thought I could just put `options(markdown.HTML.header = "<meta name=\"description\" content=\"this is a description\">")` in a chunk. However, that still doesn't work despite `getOption("markdown.HTML.header")` returning the expected result. I'm assuming that `markdownToHTML()` is not using the default `header` parameters when called, and so this would be impossible since you can't affect how that function is called from within the .Rmd?

Comment: RStudio does not use the markdown package in R. It has its own renderer based on the same library (sundown). I knew there was going to be a confusion, and I meant [this](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/markdown_custom_rendering) when I said "customization".

Comment: Hi @Yihui, I'm having a similar problem and I cant access that RStudio support page.  Could you post a quick answer, or give a link to a more accessible site?

Answer (score 0):

You use a line in the yaml header that reads in an external .html file with your header snippet in it as [per this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43334558/5579281).

Here is a slight modification from the link above including your code and includes the option the creation of the external .html header text in the .Rmd file which is not required:

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  html_document:
    includes:
       in_header: header.html
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
# Create header.html
CON <- file("header.html")
writeLines('<meta name="description" content="this is a description" />', CON)
close(CON)
```
````