# R Markdown Add Tag to Head of HTML Output

Tags: r, r-markdown

How do I add an HTML meta tag within the head of an RMarkdown HTML output file from RStudio?

In particular I am trying to insert the following to over come IE compatibility issues on our intranet.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
```

Comment: The discussion in the comments here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748205/insert-tags-in-header-via-rmd

Comment: I looked at that, but I do not believe it is helpful...

Comment: When I did this it had to be added as the very first `<meta>` tag, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009148/add-x-ua-compatible-in-rmarkdown-html-output/54676307#54676307

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a file with the meta tag and add using the following YAML option:

```
---
title: "mytitle"
output:
  html_document:
    includes:
       in_header: myheader.html
---
```

You could also create the `myheader.html` file on the fly in the setup chunck:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE )
#libraries
require(ggplot2)

#Create myheader.html
fileConn <- file("myheader.html")
writeLines('<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />', fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```
````

Comment: Do you know if there's any way of providing a string value to `in_header` rather than a file path? The reason I ask is [in an attempt to solve an analogous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61528612/how-to-include-font-face-within-style-tag-of-rmarkdown) I will try to provide a string value to `in_header` (in my case, a `<style>` tag)

Answer (score 4):

Use `library(metathis)` !

Then include with:

````
```{r include=F}
meta() %>%
  meta_description("My awesome App")
```
````

And any other meta tag

Comment: It might be great to add the more general case that is very useful today, "property"/"content" tags like og tags . . . . . . 
meta_tag(
      "property"="og:title",
      content="--your title--"
  )