# Add X-UA-Compatible in rmarkdown html output

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to add the following tag

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

as the **first** one after `<header>` in the output of rmkardown HTML document. This is necessary for Internet Explorer, as explained in this MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43329230/r-markdown-add-tag-to-head-of-html-output) does not work for me because the tag is added at the end of `<head>` and is ignored. My HTML output has some script embedded that is written before the X-UA-Compatible meta tag.

Is there a way to add the tag as the first one automatically in rmarkdown?

Comment: you'll have to use your custom template file... not sure about knitr, but for standalone pandoc see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates

Comment: Thanks, I found the tamplate being used by rmarkdown and added the necessary meta tag. In order to make it independent of the user I will try to change the default template used by rmarkdown::render.

Comment: the standard template can be edited in the library folder, e.g. "C:\Users\ProfileX\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html"

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue too. As people have said in the comments, editing the template html file used by rmarkdown works. I copied and edited the template saved at approximately "C:\Users\ProfileX\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" (thanks @visu-l)

You want to add the tag as the first one within `<head>`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"$if(lang)$ lang="$lang$" xml:lang="$lang$"$endif$>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Then save the html template, and point to it within YAML:

```
---
title: "xxx"
output:
  html_document:
    template: path/to/custom/template.html
---
```